# Trying to nest a custom object proxy in a dict proxy

Tags: python, multiprocessing

As per [the documentation provided by Python here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects), having a nested proxy object in another is fine; I already use this quite a bit. The problem however lies when I try to create my own object proxy, mainly because it has to exist and update itself.

For context, I'm on Python 3.6.9.

Here is an example I made to explain the problem I am having:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Manager

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, num) -> None:
        self.num = num
    
    def inc(self) -> None:
        self.num += 1
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"Current num: {self.num}"

SyncManager.register('Foo', Foo)

with Manager() as manager:
    # Create new managed dict
    test_dict = manager.dict()

    # Create new normal object in managed dict
    test_dict['t1'] = Foo(1)
    print(test_dict['t1'])

    # Try to update object in managed dict
    test_dict['t1'].inc()
    print(test_dict['t1']) # Not updated since it is not managed

    # Managed object NOT in managed dict
    test_obj = manager.Foo(10)
    print(test_obj._getvalue()) # Get actual object

    # Increment managed object
    test_obj.inc()
    print(test_obj._getvalue()) # Get actual object

    # Managed object IN managed dict
    test_dict['t2'] = manager.Foo(100) # Error
    print(test_dict['t2'])
```

The output of the above is as follows:

```
Current num: 1
Current num: 1
Current num: 10
Current num: 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 37, in <module>
    test_dict['t2'] = manager.Foo(100) # Error
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 772, in _callmethod
    raise convert_to_error(kind, result)
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 228, in serve_client
    request = recv()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 881, in RebuildProxy
    return func(token, serializer, incref=incref, **kwds)
TypeError: AutoProxy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'manager_owned'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From here, I can use the managed dict with no issues. I can create the managed object without issues either. Trying to put the latter in the former though causes the problem.

Now the error I got here was specifically due to AutoProxy() being given an extra argument, which is a known issue. I decided to make my own quick proxy to get past it.

So I updated the following lines:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

SyncManager.register('Foo', Foo)
```

to:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager, MakeProxyType, public_methods

SyncManager.register('Foo', Foo, MakeProxyType('Foo', public_methods(Foo)))
```

The output is now:

```
Current num: 1
Current num: 1
Current num: 10
Current num: 11
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 37, in <module>
    test_dict['t2'] = manager.Foo(100) # Error
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 756, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.managers.Foo'>: attribute lookup Foo on multiprocessing.managers failed
```

It's failing at trying to pickle... I'm not sure; it should be the proxy, and not the object, right? I tried to pickle `manager.Foo(1)`, and got the same error; which was to be expected.

I'm stumped. I need to have the objects that are in a `manager.dict()` to be updated, and I can't simply replace the object with a new one with new parameters.

I can't use any newer version of Python, and I can't figure this out. Any help here would be appreciated.